# Usage of GSL Dilogarithm function in C++

Tags: c++, complex-numbers, gsl

I'm trying to use the dilogarithm function provided by the GSL library for a C++ program. I get how to call the function for a real argument (which returns a real number):

```
gsl_sf_dilog(double x)
```

But in cases where the argument is complex, I don't understand how to call the function correctly. The GSL manual says that for a complex argument, the function is called as follows:

```
int gsl_sf_complex_dilog_e (double r, double theta, gsl_sf_result *result_re, gsl_sf_result * result_im)
```

What I want out of the program is `result_re`: the real part of the dilogarithm. But I just get errors with everything I've tried so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gsl/gsl_sf_dilog.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_sf_result.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <complex>

int main (void)
{
  double res1, res2;
  double dilog = gsl_sf_complex_dilog_e(3.,M_PI/2.,      gsl_sf_result*res1,gsl_sf_result*res2);
  return 0;
}
```

I get this error when I try to compile: `error: expected primary-expression before ‘*’ token` and `error: expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]`

Can someone tell me how I can get this function to work? Thanks

Comment: What's the '\' backslash for in the `gsl_sf_complex_dilog_e` call?

Comment: My bad. I put those in to signify that it should all be on the same line, there's no backslash in the function call. I've edited it to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass in pointers to [`gsl_sf_result`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/The-gsl_005fsf_005fresult-struct.html) structs not doubles as you are attempting to.

You can get the result from the `val` members of these structures.

A corrected version of your code would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <gsl/gsl_sf_dilog.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_sf_result.h>

int main()
{
    gsl_sf_result re, im;
    gsl_sf_complex_dilog_e(3., M_PI/2., &re, &im);

    std::cout << re.val << " + " << im.val << "i" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Which outputs:

```
-0.987666 + 2.05507i
```